# lower function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to use lower function in postgres to convert upper special chars to lower special chars. For exam: `SELECT lower('Ş')`. Its result is '`Ş`' not '`ş`'.

Comment: You need to see the encoding that you're using.

Comment: utf8mb4. you ask this?

Comment: Don't you need a collation that defines the upper/lower mapping for such characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose the correct collation:

```
SELECT lower('Ş' COLLATE "C");
 lower 
-------
 Ş
(1 row)

SELECT lower('Ş' COLLATE "az_AZ.utf8");
 lower 
-------
 ş
(1 row)
```

If you do not choose a collation explicitly, it is taken from the collation of the column or (lacking that) the collation of the database which you can display with `\l`.

It is usually a good idea to choose the database collation wisely so that you don't have to specify a collation explicitly.